# Remove duplicates values from dropdown in php

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hi all i am trying to remove duplicate values from my dropdown. But somehow i couldn't able to understand how to do.

Here is my code:

```
 /**
     * Get order ticket details
     */
    public function ticketDetailsAction()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderId', 0);
        $contactId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contactId', 0);
        $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $ticketService = new Tickets_Service_Ticket($bootstrap->getOptions());
        $userId = $this->getUserInfo()->getId();
        $params = array(
            'depotAndAffiliateIds' => array_keys($this->_affiliatedDepotMastersWithActiveDepot),
            'orderId' => $orderId,
            'contactId' => (int)$contactId,
            'user' => $userId,
        );
        $options = array(
            'language' => BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::LANGUAGE_DEFAULT,
            'user' => $userId,
            'translate' => $bootstrap->getResource('translate'),
            'config' => $bootstrap->getResource('config'),
        );
        $ticketGridService = new Ticket_Service_Grid($ticketService, $options);
        if (0 < (int)$contactId) {
            $this->view->ticketGridObject =  $ticketGridService->getGrid(Ticket_Service_Grid::GRID_TYPE_ORDERTICKETOVERVIEW, $params);
        }
        if (empty($this->view->ticketGridObject)) {
            $where = array('depot_id in (?)' => array_keys($this->_affiliatedDepotMastersWithActiveDepot));
            $this->view->ticketSources = $ticketService->getTicketSourceList($where);
        }
    }


 /**
 * Get ticket source list
 * 
 * @param array $whereCondition
 * @return array
 */
public function getTicketSourceList($whereCondition = array())
{
    /** @var BAS_Shared_Model_TicketSourceMapper  */
    $ticketSource = $this->getMapper('TicketSource');

    return $ticketSource->findAllByCondition($whereCondition, 'source ASC');
}

 /**
 * @param string|array|Zend_Db_Table_Select|null $where
 * @param string|array|null $order
 * @param int|null $count
 * @param int|null $offset
 * @return array|BAS_Shared_Model_AbstractModel[]
 */
public function findAllByCondition($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
{
    $rows = $this->getDao()->fetchAll($where, $order, $count, $offset);
    $models = [];

    while(($row = $rows->current()) !== null) {
        $models[] = $this->mapRow($row);
        $rows->next();
    }

    $this->resetMapToModel();

    return $models;
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<select id="ticketSource">
        <option value="">--<?php echo $this->translate('select') ?>--</option>
        <?php foreach ($this->ticketSources as $ticketSource) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ticketSource->source ;?>"><?php echo $ticketSource->source;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```

How can i add distinct condition here. I Have added my full controller function and remaining functions too. and i have added my view page code which will create dropdown code.

Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733117/how-to-use-distinct-in-zend-db-model ?

Comment: i haven;t write anywhere sql queries if you can see? i have taken one abstarct mapper from there i am directly fetching details

Comment: Can you please add more information like how is the dropdown now, which function creating the dropdown and how?

Comment: I think what you want to do is to loop through all values (options) and add them to an array as you go. Before adding them to array and displaying them, check if they're not already in the array. If positive, skip the entry.